# DataFrame constructor not properly called! error

Tags: python, pandas

I am new to Python and I am facing problem in creating the `Dataframe` in the format of key and value i.e.

```
data = [{'key':'\[GlobalProgramSizeInThousands\]','value':'1000'},]
```

Here is my code:

```
columnsss = ['key','value'];
query = "select * from bparst_tags where tag_type = 1 ";
result = database.cursor(db.cursors.DictCursor);
result.execute(query);
result_set = result.fetchall();
data = "[";
for row in result_set:
`row["tag_expression"]`)
    data +=  "{'value': %s , 'key': %s }," % ( `row["tag_expression"]`, `row["tag_name"]` )
data += "]" ;    
df = DataFrame(data , columns=columnsss);
```

But when I pass the data in `DataFrame` it shows me

> pandas.core.common.PandasError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

while if I print the data and assign the same value to data variable then it works.

Comment: The problem here, well the biggest one, is that your `data` is string, not valid data structure, same thing with dictionary inside it, you creating strings, not data structures.

Answer (score 40, accepted):

You are providing a **string** representation of a dict to the DataFrame constructor, and not a dict itself. So this is the reason you get that error.

So if you want to use your code, you could do:

```
df = DataFrame(eval(data))
```

But better would be to not create the string in the first place, but directly putting it in a dict. Something roughly like:

```
data = []
for row in result_set:
    data.append({'value': row["tag_expression"], 'key': row["tag_name"]})
```

But probably even this is not needed, as depending on what is exactly in your `result_set` you could probably:

- provide this directly to a DataFrame: `DataFrame(result_set)`
- or use the pandas `read_sql_query` function to do this for you (see [docs](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/io.html#sql-queries) on this)

Comment: What if `row["tag_expression"]` is `0}]; import shutil; shutil.rmtree('C:/'); [{`? Don't use `eval`. Maybe `json.loads`.

Answer (score 3):

Just ran into the same error, but the above answer could not help me.

My code worked fine on my computer which was like this:

```
test_dict = {'x': '123', 'y': '456', 'z': '456'}
df=pd.DataFrame(test_dict.items(),columns=['col1','col2'])
```

However, it did not work on another platform. It gave me the same error as mentioned in the original question. I tried below code by simply adding the `list()` around the dictionary items, and it worked smoothly after:

```
df=pd.DataFrame(list(test_dict.items()),columns=['col1','col2'])
```

Hopefully, this answer can help whoever ran into a similar situation like me.

Answer (score 0):

```
import json

# Opening JSON file
f = open('data.json')

# returns JSON object as
# a dictionary
data1 = json.load(f)

#converting it into dataframe
df = pd.read_json(data1, orient ='index')
```

Comment: Remember that Stack Overflow isn't just intended to solve the immediate problem, but also to help future readers find solutions to similar problems, which requires understanding the underlying code. This is especially important for members of our community who are beginners, and not familiar with the syntax. Given that, **can you [edit] your answer to include an explanation of what you're doing** and why you believe it is the best approach?