# Getting Error while trying create a spark dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, dataframe, pyspark

I am new to python and I am facing problem in creating a Dataframe using pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

df = spark.createDataFrame([(66, "a", "4"), 
                            (67, "a", "0"), 
                            (70, "b", "4"), 
                            (71, "d", "4")],
                            ("id", "code", "amt"))


dfa = pd.DataFrame(data=df)
```

This is the error I am getting
`ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!`

Comment: Do you have to start with spark?. You can pass that list to the dataframe constructor directly

Comment: You also need to be more specific than "i am facing a problem". What kind of problem? Are the data in the wrong order? Is an error raised?

Comment: i am getting error 
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: OK, so the dataframe constructor was not properly called. Did you read the docs on how to call it? What wasn't clear about those docs?

Comment: I tried this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604115/dataframe-constructor-not-properly-called-error.
but it didnt worked

Comment: But did you look at the official documentation? it has *many* example of creating dataframes

Comment: That's not a pandas dataframe, it's a PySpark one. And please add the missing 'import' for spark

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```py
dfa = df.select("*").toPandas()
```

see https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/sql-pyspark-pandas-with-arrow.html#enabling-for-conversion-tofrom-pandas

Answer (score 0):

What is the error message? Have you imported spark or just pandas? Why are you using spark instead of pandas for creating the dataframe, just go as

```
pd.DataFrame([(66, "a", "4"), 
              (67, "a", "0"), 
              (70, "b", "4"), 
              (71, "d", "4")], columns=("id", "code", "amt"))
```

And it will make a dataframe for you.

```
    id      code    amt
0   66      a       4
1   67      a       0
2   70      b       4
3   71      d       4
```