# How can I turn this list of strings into a dataframe in pandas

Tags: python, pandas, bioservices

Ok so essentially I extracted a large list of values from a database online using the bioservices package. What I want to do if turn this list of strings into a dataframe using pandas that I can then further format.

[this is my extracted list of values from the online database that I want to turn into a pandas datafram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QOS8O.png)

Comment: What is your desired output? what was tried to reach the goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work for you. Just replace my list with yours.

```
import pandas as pd
d = ['your', 'list']
df = pd.DataFrame(columns= ['col1'],
                  data=d)
print(df)
```

Comment: thank you so much for the answer, I feel as thought I am really close with your code but unfortunately I am getting an error that says 
"raise ValueError("DataFrame constructor not properly called!")
ValueError: DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: It might have something to do with the fact that your data is string. This might help you here. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604115/dataframe-constructor-not-properly-called-error