# How to convert a python dictionary with tuples into a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, dictionary, tuples

I have a python dictionary in which the keys of the dictionary are tuples of two strings and the values are integers.

It looks like this:

```
mydic = { ('column1', 'index1'):33, 
          ('column1', 'index2'):34, 
          ('column2', 'index1'):35, 
          ('column2', 'index2'):36 }
```

The first string of the tuples should be used as the column-name in the dataframe and the second string in the tuple should be used as the index.

The dataframe from this should look like this:

| (index) | column1 | column 2 |
| --- | --- | --- |
| index1 | 33 | 35 |
| index2 | 34 | 36 |

Is there any way to do this?

(Or do I have to loop through all elements of the dictionary and build the dataframe one value at a time by hand?)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Build a [`pd.Series`](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.html) first (which will have a MultiIndex), then use [`pd.Series.unstack`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.unstack.html) to get the column names.

```
df = pd.Series(mydic).unstack(0)
print(df)
```

```
        column1  column2
index1       33       35
index2       34       36
```

Comment: Thank you, that was exactly what I was looking for. I just tried it and it is working. It only converts the Integer values to float, but otherwise perfect!

Comment: The conversion to float seemes to be caused due to NaN-Values. I added two lines to get Integers:   "df.fillna(0, inplace=True)"     and       "df=df.astype(int)"

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/1.2.0/user_guide/advanced.html#creating-a-multiindex-hierarchical-index-object).

```
mydic = { ('column1', 'index1'):33, 
          ('column1', 'index2'):34, 
          ('column2', 'index1'):35, 
          ('column2', 'index2'):36 }

df = pd.DataFrame(mydic.values(), index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(mydic))

                 0
column1 index1  33
        index2  34
column2 index1  35
        index2  36
```

What comes after that is just a workaround.

```
df.T.stack()

          column1  column2
0 index1       33       35
  index2       34       36
```

Notice that the index contains two rows. Do not forget to reset it.

```
df.T.stack().reset_index().drop('level_0', axis = 1)

  level_1  column1  column2
0  index1       33       35
1  index2       34       36
```

You can rename the `level_1` if you want to. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. But if I try the first line (df = pd.DataFrame(mydic.values(), index = pd.MultiIndex.from_tuples(mydic))) then I get an exeption: ValueError:DataFrame constructor not properly called!

Comment: Check this. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25604115/dataframe-constructor-not-properly-called-error

Comment: @Robert did you see my answer?

Comment: @Vini: I found how to prevent the Exeption: Instead of "mydic.values()" I write "list(mydic.values())". Then your code is working fine. Thank you! (Though I'm not sure, why the list() is needed here)